# Configure PhpStorm to use .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, phpstorm

I added `.htaccess` (for rewriting URLs) in my project's root directory but it's not working. I checked twice, the same file is working fine in Eclipse.

How do I configure PhpStorm to use .htaccess?

Comment: What do you mean? What do you expect PHPStorm to do about the file?

Comment: suppose there is a file called `tmp.php` in root directory then i write a rewrite rule in .htaccess
`RewriteRule ^tmp/?$ tmp.php`.

When i type `http://localhost/mysite/tmp`
it's not redirecting to `http://localhost/mysite/tmp.php`
It throw 404

Comment: When you type that where, in the browser? I'm not sure how the IDE plays into this?

Comment: It's `Apache` that has to take care of `.htaccess`, not PHP. Add AllowOverride All to your vhost.

Comment: @Pekka웃 when i use same project with eclipse it works fine
but why not working with phpstorm

Comment: What exactly is not working? Where are you typing in the URL?

Comment: When i enter go to `http://localhost/mysite/tmp` it should open
`http://localhost/mysite/tmp.php`

Comment: *sigh* **where** are you entering the URL? In which program? This likely has nothing to do with the IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the same server/configuration when working with PhpStorm and Eclipse?

As it was explained in the comments, it has nothing to do with the IDE, but with the web server (Apache) and its configuration.

You can edit `.htaccess` with any editor, if this virtualhost/directory configuration has [`AllowOverride All`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride), ModRewrite is enabled and your rewrite rules are correct, it will work just fine.

You need to ensure that your PHP files are served from the correctly configured web server.

Comment: I'm using PHP built-in webserver, I'm trying to change my default index file using htaccess, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Shqear built-in web server has no support for `.htaccess`.

Comment: @CrazeCoder yup I just figured that so I managed to use PHP router script instead as described in Victor's post

Answer (score 3):

1. Indeed, [PHP's built-in web server will never fully support `.htaccess` features](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). *Note: it is PHP's, it is NOT PHPStorm's built-in server*.

But there is a way around.

2. Most of the time, rewrites are needed only to redirect all the nonstatic file queries to `index.php`. If you only need this, [you can set the server's "router script"](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-support-of-php-5-4-built-in-web-server/) in PHPStorm run configuration to `index.php`.
3. After that, a modest hack in `index.php` to serve static files from the drive may speed things up.

Add to the very beginning of `index.php`:

```
if (preg_match('/\.(?:php|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|css|js)\??.*$/',
    $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) 
{
    return false; // serve the requested resource as-is.
}
```