# PHP Storm Built In Server Doesn't Recognize mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, phpstorm

When I run my site via apache2, all of the resources load properly.

When I run it through the PHPStorm built in server, all of the mod_rewrite rules in the .htaccess file are *not* applied, and various resources are not found (404).

I am using the "stock" settings of the PHP built-in web server (only host and document root are configured).

Comment: Please note: PhpStorm supports 2 built-in kind of servers: PHP's own built-in web server (since PHP 5.3) .. and PhpStorm's built-in **simple** web server (since v7, I believe). None of them supports mod_rewrite rules, of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure phpstorm to use .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569493/configure-phpstorm-to-use-htaccess)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the built-in server is *not* Apache? You might want to [remote debug](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Remote_JavaScript_debugging_with_WebStorm_and_PHPStorm) instead.

Comment: I am using remote debug, but I like using the built in PHP server just so that I can read the errors easily.