# .htaccess file won't respond on localhost:63342 in PhpStorm

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using the IDE PhpStorm 7.1.4 and trying to make an .htaccess file to stop users from going into a specific directory.

My folder structure is like this:

[image]

I want to make it so that users can't go in the `/app` folder or any folders inside that folder. For this, I've figured out that I can use this piece of code inside `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
```

I'm using the PHP web server from PHPStorm itself (which goes to `localhost:63342/projectname/folderinproject/etc/etc/`).

**Problems**

- When directing to the page to the `/app` folder, I get an 404 error,
  saying the index file doesn't exist.
- When I have made an `index.php` file inside the `/app` folder, and I am redirecting to the `/app` folder, it just loading up the `index.php`.
- When doing this with just a normal HTML project and opening the `index.html` via my windows explorer, the same problem occurs

**Question**

How can I make it so that my project would actually respond on the `.htaccess` file and wont allow me or other users to go into the `/app` folder?

---

**EDIT**

I figured out that when I copy all my files from my project to the `c:\xampp\htdocs\` folder and turn on my Apache server inside of XAMPP, the `.htaccess` file is working whenever I open it via my regular browser (without selecting `index.php` in PhpStorm and choosing `Open in browser...`).

Is there any way I can do this same thing in PhpStorm without moving all the files?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess

Comment: @Dave It's the same thing, its giving me a 404 error. Because there  exists no index.php file. But when there is, it just works.

Comment: Did you tried `Options All -Indexes` ?

Comment: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Comment: @vlzvl Yes, and i didnt work aswell.. :\ could it be because of i dont get actually the file explorer system? Like when i open it via my browser. (The apache server)

Comment: @hakiko I knew this already, thanks for the great article though :). But it just doesnt seem that it reacts on the file, whatever code is in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure phpstorm to use .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569493/configure-phpstorm-to-use-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default configured web server, you are actually using PHP's new web server feature, which doesn't listen to `.htaccess` files.  Only Apache listens to `.htaccess` files.

If you are wanting to test this functionality, you can either setup a VM running Linux and test, or setup [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) on your system and run from there.

## EDIT 1

---

Ok, can you add a little more detail about the exact problem?  When you access `localhost/app/` it is displaying the `index.php` file, instead of the `404`. Does the application work entirely through the `index.php` file?  If so, is the `index.php` file in the `app` or `public`?

## EDIT 2

---

Ok, here's what you need to do.  Place an `.htaccess` file in the root of your app directory.  Clear the contents of this `.htaccess` and place the line `DENY from ALL`.  You can keep the `.htaccess` file in the root of the project.

## EDIT 3

---

PHPStorm is going to use the PHP Engine's web server. If you add the XAMPP location as a deployment path, it's fairly quick to deploy to. You can even setup PHPStorm to automatically deploy files to the XAMPP location on save. Here's the walk-through on the JetBrains site [JetBrains Config](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE#InstallingandConfiguringXAMPPwithPhpStormIDE-IntegratingtheApacheserver).

The `.htaccess` plugins are mainly for editing and formating, not for modifying PHP Engine's server environment.

Comment: This didn't work, I tried it with my apache server on, without running phpstorm. And still the same problem occurs.

Comment: When I access the folder `localhost/app`, and there is no index file in it, it gives me an `404` error, with text beneath it `Index file is not found`. Also, the version of PHPstorm is being shown on that same screen. Whenever I put an `index.php` file inside that `localhost/app` folder. And i access that folder, it just loads that file, without any errors.

Comment: Can you post your entire `.htaccess`?

Comment: Sorry but i already did.. Those are all the contents. It doesnt seem that the phpstorm server (63342) has support for this htaccess file?

Comment: Alright, i figured out that when i place my project files into the `htdocs` folder from `xampp`, and then go to that with any contents inside the `.htaccess` file, it works. Is there any way phpstorm can do this on its own server? (63342) So i dont have to move all the files every time

Comment: No. PHPStorm is going to use the PHP Engine's web server.  If you add the XAMPP location as a deployment path, it's fairly quick to deploy to.  You can even setup PHPStorm to automatically deploy files to the XAMPP location on save.  Here's the walk-through on the JetBrains site http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE#InstallingandConfiguringXAMPPwithPhpStormIDE-IntegratingtheApacheserver

Comment: Aw okay, is deploying the only workaround? Because i have seen some plug-in for phpstorm that says it has support for the .htaccess file. Or is that only about the code hinting? Btw if you can edit that in your answer i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Using mod_alias is even easier:

```
Redirect 301 /app /new_directory
```

But if you have rewrite rules in your htaccess file already, then you need to stick with using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ /new_directory/$1 [L,R=301]
```