# How to use .htaccess file from PhpStorm?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web, phpstorm

I have created a `.htaccess` file in the root folder of my project. I am using PhpStorm and it has a default server I think. `.htaccess` is not working from the PhpStorm server. But when i placed my project in `htdocs` folder of XAMPP, it works perfectly. But from the PhpStorm, it can not run.

How can I fix this? I want to redirect anything like: `domain.com/<any string except php file>` to my `index.php` file.

Comment: Hey, try to read here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569493/configure-phpstorm-to-use-htaccess

Comment: *"How can I fix this"* Use your XAMPP (Apache). PhpStorm's built-in **simple web server** does not really support `.htaccess` files, only limited set of instructions. Why would you want to use built-in simple web server if you have proper production-like software (Apache), which will behave more close to the actual production usage.

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm has a [Built-In Web Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-built-in-web-server.html) for *static* assets:

> The built in server can only serve static content like HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

You can also configure a PHP interpreter and use the [PHP Built-In Web Server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

> When the interpreter is configured, PhpStorm will automatically start the PHP Built-In Web Server and redirect all PHP requests to it as soon as you run your PHP application.

None of these two pieces of software have anything to do with [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/), nor will they use its settings.

These facilities are only intended to provide a quick way to test web sites without the need of installing additional software. Since you already have additional software, there's really no benefit.